# How does WPF handle Windows Forms Resources functionality?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, resources, internationalization

Does the introduction of WPF deprecates the Windows Forms Resources in any way?
With Windows Forms Resources we could:

- Provide internationalization for strings (i18n)
- Embed images into the executable

Since I haven't found an easy way for consuming those resources directly from the XAML, I suppose there is an alternative which works better with WPF. Is that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedded images work very easily in WPF.  Just add the image to your Solution (with a type of Resource), and WPF can reference it from XAML, pulling it out of the resources directly.  This is completely seamless.

Internationalization is a bit trickier, though.  You can internationalize strings using resource files, just like in Windows Forms.  However, strings within XAML are not handled the same way.  There are [two approaches to internationalization in WPF](http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/internationalization-in-net-and-wpf-presentation-foundation) - both of which require a bit more effort than Windows Forms.  However, there is a lot more flexibility and power in WPF internationalization.

First, you can use a markup extension to internationalize a string in WPF.  This requires some custom plumbing to be written, but works more like the Windows Forms approach.

The more powerful approach is to actually load different XAML based on the region.  This allows you to not only change your strings, but also adapt your UI layout - hence the extra power and flexibility (at the cost of more design time).

Comment: I would like to add that to embed images in the executable you must right click your image in the Solution Explorer, and Properties, and set the `Build Action` to `Resource`

Comment: @Jader: Very true - that was why I had mentioned setting the type to Resource.  Thank you for clarifying exactly how to do this.

Comment: I wonder if this was the same way we embedded images in previous versions of .NET Framework. If that's true, I misattributed this feature to WinForms Resources

Comment: @Jader: This has worked forever - though there are other options, as well.  You can do this in any .NET application, as its not tied to a GUI framework/tech.

Comment: So I wonder what was the purpose of WinForms resources besides i18n since it doesn't help to embed images.